# Figure ref, switch number and figure caption

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, hungarian

When I am using `\autoref{fig:lion}` the the output look like this: `Ábra 1` (this is a hungarian document and it means Figure 1). And when I am hovering over the reference text, the text (`Ábra 1`) shines yellow (I am using overleaf editor).

Is there a way to switch from `Ábra 1` into `1. ábra`, when I am referencing a figure, the whole reference text should shine yellow, when I am hovering over the reference text.

Sometimes the reference output should look like this: `1. ábrán`, cuz sometimes we are using suffix after a word, so this case, the reference text should look like this `1. ábrán`, and when I am hovering over the reference text, the text (`1. ábrán`) should shine yellow.

If I am using `\ref{fig:lion}` then the output looks like this `1`, so I have to use `\ref{fig:lion}. ábra` or `\ref{fig:lion}. ábrán`, but when I am hovering over the text, only the number shines yellow. I want the whole reference text to shine yellow when I am hovering over the reference text.

I hope that makes sense.

The only solution is that I can think of is `\hyperref[fig:lion]{1. ábra}`, but I do not know how to build a custome figure ref counter.

By the way, in the document I am referencing a figure several time, sometimes in a different `section`.

Other thing is that, there are multiple suffixes in Hungarian language, `1. ábrán` is just one of them.

**UPDATE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\selectlanguage{magyar}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\marginsize{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{1.0cm}{1.0cm} % anysize package

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,        
    unicode=false,           
    pdftitle={...},       
    pdfauthor={...},   
    pdfsubject={...}, 
    pdfcreator={...},   
    pdfproducer={Producer},   
    pdfkeywords={keywords},  
    pdfnewwindow=true,     
    colorlinks=true,          
    linkcolor=black,          
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{lion.jpg}   
  \caption{Lion}
  \label{fig:lion}
\end{figure}

\autoref{fig:lion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Please provide `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: As MadyYuvi suggests, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Then it is a lot easier to see what exactly you are doing and suggest help. As it is now, we have no clue as to what you are doing, what class and packages etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have just added.

Comment: Instead of `graphics` you should load `graphicx`.

Comment: @MadyYuvi do you have any idea, who to solve this problem. I have just clarified my question.

Comment: `cleveref.sty` is one of the best suggestion...

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load the `t1enc` package; instead, run `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` may be omitted entirely, unless you're using a *really old" TeX distribution. (Like, more than 5 years old.) There can be no justification for loading the `epsfig` package, unless your TeX distribution is about 20 years old.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I am new to latex, this is a 6 years old template from github (university stuff)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,magyar]{report}

\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{babel}
\selectlanguage{magyar}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\marginsize{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{1.0cm}{1.0cm} % anysize package

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,        
    unicode=false,           
    pdftitle={...},       
    pdfauthor={...},   
    pdfsubject={...}, 
    pdfcreator={...},   
    pdfproducer={Producer},   
    pdfkeywords={keywords},  
    pdfnewwindow=true,     
    colorlinks=true,          
    linkcolor=black,          
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\crefformat{figure}{#2#1.~ábra#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{lion.jpg}   
  \caption{Lion}
  \label{fig:lion}
\end{figure}

\cref{fig:lion}

\end{document}
```

Note that i moved the `magyar` option to the class declaration, as it is recommended to do so by the `cleveref` manual when using babel.

Here is another approach, but i don't know how robust it is. You can define a new command using `\hyperref` in the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\selectlanguage{magyar}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\marginsize{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{1.0cm}{1.0cm} % anysize package

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,        
    unicode=false,           
    pdftitle={...},       
    pdfauthor={...},   
    pdfsubject={...}, 
    pdfcreator={...},   
    pdfproducer={Producer},   
    pdfkeywords={keywords},  
    pdfnewwindow=true,     
    colorlinks=true,          
    linkcolor=black,          
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\newcommand*\myref[2][ábra]{\hyperref[#2]{\ref*{#2}.~#1}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}   
        \caption{Lion}
        \label{fig:lion}
    \end{figure}
    
    \myref{fig:lion}
    
    \myref[ábrán]{fig:lion}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okey, that is a neat solution but not precise, as I already said in my question, sometimes we are using, suffixes, so sometimes the ref output text should look like this: `1. ábrán`, not `1. ábra`

Comment: @mala97 -- `cleveref`'s `\cref` command and friends can handle only the nominative case. For other cases -- I'm afraid I have no idea how many cases Hungarian may have, let alone what they're called -- use `\labelcref` along with the appropriate case format.

Comment: Okey, thanks for your help, maybe others have precise solution for this problem.

Comment: In hungarian there are several different suffixes, thus I have just came up with one.

Comment: @mala97, See my edit.

Comment: What a solution, that is working, thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: @mala97 I suppose what you are calling "suffixes" there are actually declension cases. Is this correct? If so, `zref-clever` does have some support for it (https://ctan.org/pkg/zref-clever), but (at least currently) has no localization for Hungarian.

Comment: @Mico ^^^ You may be interested as well.

Comment: @mala97, After some thoughts you might want to change the space in the hyperlink to be unbreakable, by replacing the space with ~. also you should probably use `\newcommad*` and not `\newcommand`.